# Error when closing file

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code that is working fine, but when I close the file I have error code.
Problem is in the logic where I want to search the next empty cell in column "C" after C24.

```
Private Sub ComboBox21_Change()
Dim NextFree As String
Dim Comboindex As Integer
Dim Combovalue As String

Comboindex = Sheet1.ComboBox21.ListIndex + 1
Combovalue = Sheet1.ComboBox21.Value

'NextFree = Range("C24:C" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each cell In ws.Range("C24:C100")
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        NextFree = cell.Row
              Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If NextFree > 25 Then
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")
With ws1
    Set Rng = .Rows(NextFree - 1)
    Rng.Copy
    Rng.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    .Range("C" & NextFree & ":H" & NextFree).ClearContents
End With
End If

Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 3).Value = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Comboindex, 1).Value
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 5).Value = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Comboindex, 2).Value
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 6).Value = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Comboindex, 3).Value
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 8).Value = "=+F" & NextFree & "-(G" & NextFree & "*F" & NextFree & ")"

TotalHTF = "=SUM(H25:H" & NextFree & ")"
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 1, 8).Value = TotalHTF
TotalHT = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 1, 8).Value

TVAF = "=H" & NextFree + 1 & "*0.2"
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 2, 8).Value = TVAF
TVA = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 2, 8).Value

NetF = "=H" & NextFree + 1 & "+H" & NextFree + 2
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 3, 8).Value = NetF
Net = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 3, 8).Value

End Sub
```

As for now error when closing the file is:
"Object Variable or With Block variable not set"

In line:

```
For Each cell In ws.Range("C24:C100")
```

As you can see, I have tried also before using the option:

```
'NextFree = Range("C24:C" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
```

This also worked, but had below error when closing the file:
"Unable to get the SpecialCells property of the Range class"

Any ideas how to do it?

Regards,

Brian

Comment: what file are you closing?

Comment: the for each loop works fine. You need to replace `sheet1` and `sheet2` with Worksheets("Sheet1") and Worksheets("Sheet2") or define them at the beginning.

Comment: Error is when I close excel file that has this code. Now I have changed the code from sheet1 to Worksheet("Sheet1") but i still having same error when document is close. Initial code updated. Error: "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: Insert the line `Debug.Print ws Is Nothing, TypeName(ws)` below the line `Set ws = ActiveSheet`.  What does it output?

Comment: When i execute the code, the output is : False         Worksheet.      But when I close the file the output is: True          Nothing. Not sure how to understand it...Thanks for your help.

Comment: you still have `sheet1` in your combo box lines.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I still have problems when file is close. As for VBA Pete suggested code, when file is close, it shows: Method Worksheets of object_Global failed, in    Comboindex = Worksheets("Feuil1").ComboBox21.ListIndex + 1    . If instead I leave this part with Sheet1 as before , I still have error : Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: Adding the debug line, the output is the same as the one reported before.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Comboindex and Combovalue?

Comment: These are the index number and value of the combo box.  In fact I am not using the value right now, but I use the index to get data from sheet2. Not sure why it only gives error when I close the file and not when I am executing the code through the combo box change.

Comment: Even if I deactive those two lines I have same error when file is close.

Answer (score 0):

- Change sheet1 to Worksheet("Sheet1") - combobox items at the top still show sheet1
- `Dim ws1 as worksheet` as you currently do not have it defined.
- `Dim nextfree as long` as it is a number
- One other thing. Change your code on the bottom to:

  Dim TotalHT As Variant, TVA As Variant, Net As Variant

  Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 1, 8).Formula = "=SUM(H25:H" & NextFree & ")"
  TotalHT = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 1, 8).Value

  Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 2, 8).Formula = "=H" & NextFree + 1 & "*0.2"""
  TVA = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 2, 8).Value

  Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 3, 8).Formula = "=H" & NextFree + 1 & "+H" & NextFree + 2
  Net = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 3, 8).Value

Try the full code below:

```
Private Sub ComboBox21_Change()
Dim Comboindex As long, NextFree As long
Dim Combovalue As String
Dim TotalHT As Variant, TVA As Variant, Net As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet

Comboindex = Worksheets("Feuil1").ComboBox21.ListIndex + 1
Combovalue = Worksheets("Feuil1").ComboBox21.Value

'NextFree = Range("C24:C" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each cell In ws.Range("C24:C100")
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
        NextFree = cell.Row
              Exit For
    End If
Next cell

If NextFree > 25 Then
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")
    With ws1
        Set Rng = .Rows(NextFree - 1)
        Rng.Copy
        Rng.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range("C" & NextFree & ":H" & NextFree).ClearContents
    End With
End If

Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 3).Value = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Comboindex, 1).Value
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 5).Value = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Comboindex, 2).Value
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 6).Value = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Comboindex, 3).Value
Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree, 8).Formula = "=+F" & NextFree & "-(G" & NextFree & "*F" & NextFree & ")"

Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 1, 8).Formula = "=SUM(H25:H" & NextFree & ")"
TotalHT = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 1, 8).Value

Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 2, 8).Formula = "=H" & NextFree + 1 & "*0.2"""
TVA = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 2, 8).Value

Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 3, 8).Formula = "=H" & NextFree + 1 & "+H" & NextFree + 2
Net = Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(NextFree + 3, 8).Value

End Sub
```